# Cleanest way to start a WebAPI project in Visual Studio (NO VIEWS)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

What's the cleanest way to remove all extras that normally come with Visual Studio API Template, things like Views and other stuff that are not needed if you just want to have a WebAPI service??

I'm assuming that the folder VIEWS is for MVC Views ...maybe I'm wrong and it's all needed to have a running APIs.

Comment: This is a bit late but Ive just come across it. Here is a good article if you are starting from scratch: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api All you need do is create a controller class and override the 'ApiController' and you are pretty much there.

Comment: There's an even cleaner way then selecting Empty. Here's a GitHub project I've that aims to setup the most basic yet functional WebApi project setup. https://github.com/duluca/oneapi

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Launch Visual Studio
2. go to `File` -> `New Project` -> `ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application`.
3. Click OK
4. then select "Empty" instead of "Web API"

That will not have any extras such as Views.

Comment: It will have Web API dll references and FilterConfig, RouteConfig and WebApiConfig files. What others are you hoping for?

Comment: I'm starting with WebAPI so I don't know what resources are specifically needed solely for APIs. I guess your list is the right one?

Comment: I've found this ..based on your comment
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=921

Comment: Yeah that is a good starting point if you don't need all the other views/api helper pages etc. that come with the default template (although I think the default template is a great starting point too and then you can remove things from it that you don't need). I would also start using Nuget to manage your Web API packages. Right click on the empty solution you created, say Manage Nuget Packages for Solution and search for Web API and install it there.

Comment: +1 using NuGet to add the Web API packages. Use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package. You'll also need the config code, which you can copy from the Web API template. This is improved in VS2013, there is now an option to add just Web API to the Empty template.

Answer (score 19):

1. Launch Visual Studio
2. Go To File -> New Project -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application
3. Enter name and press Ok
4. Select Empty from Templates and then Select Web API from "Add folders and core references for: " section
5. Press Ok
6. You will get an empty web api project with all necessary dlls and web appi configuration added in the project.
7. You will have to add your first controller by yourself though.

[image]