# Purpose of "views" in ASP.NET MVC WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am a bit confused regarding the purpose of "Views" in ASP.NET MVC WEB API. According to my knowledge ASP.NET MVC WEB API is used for writing services, so if we are only writing services then what is the purpose of views in it. 
PS: whenever i make a new ASP.NET MVC WEB API project, visual studio also makes the Views folder.[Please find attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksgLY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are optional in an MVC project.  They are only used for projects where there are HTML pages involved.  You can use MVC to build web services and they don't require Views.

Here's an older question but I think it's relevant: [Cleanest way to start a WebAPI project in Visual Studio (NO VIEWS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150879/cleanest-way-to-start-a-webapi-project-in-visual-studio-no-views)

Comment: So you mean to say there is no difference between ASP.NET MVC project and ASP.NET MVC WEB API Project ?? We can develop WEB API in ASP.NET MVC project ?

Comment: I'm not saying there's no difference, I'm saying you basically use the same technology to create two different kinds of projects.  WebApi is like MVC without the V.